# OpenSSL error 0x2006D002 when creating CSR

Tags: php, openssl

I have error

```
error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib
```

when calling `openssl_csr_new` function.

```
$pKey = openssl_pkey_new( $keyConfig );
$pCSR = openssl_csr_new( $sslConfig, $pKey );
```

Without `openssl.cnf` this failed on first function.

I try a minimum `openssl.cnf` and real configuration, but no effect. If I use wrong `openssl.cnf` error will be:

```
error:0E064002:configuration file routines:CONF_load:system lib
```

Please, can you help with correct minimum `openssl.cnf` or that I need fix?

- PHP 5.3.28 as Apache mod;
- phpinfo: OpenSSL support enabled
- OpenSSL Library Version 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
- PHP reinstalled and already rebooted.

Comment: `openssl errstr 0x2006D002` returns `error:2006D002:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:system lib`. A file or directory probably does not exist. Does the error occur with `keyConfig` or `sslConfig`?

Comment: I think, that I alredy found my error. Openssl_csr_new function can take third argument - it must be $keyConfig from openssl_pkey_new. I check next code later and write here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, I need specify $keyConfig for OpenSSL function :

```
$keyConfig = array(
    'config' => dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) . '/store/openssl.cnf',
    ...
);
$sslConfig = array(
    "countryName" => 'XX',
    "stateOrProvinceName" => 'XX',
    "localityName" => 'XX',
    ...
);
$pKey = openssl_pkey_new( $keyConfig );
$pCSR = openssl_csr_new( $sslConfig, $pKey , $keyConfig );
$pCRT = openssl_csr_sign( $pCSR , null , $pKey , self::TIME_INTERVAL_WEEK , $keyConfig );
openssl_x509_export( $pCRT, $strCertificate );
openssl_pkey_export( $pKey, $strPrivateKey , null , $keyConfig );
```